# How to disable JMX bean to show up in Spring Boot Admin console

Tags: spring-boot, jmx, spring-boot-admin

I have enabled jmx in my spring boot application which is registering itself as client with Spring Boot Admin. I want to hide the Tomcat option from the Domains list.

[image]

Is there a way to hide the Tomcat option?

Comment: Spring Boot Admin just shows the data that is provided by actuator endpoints. These jmx operations here are provided by jolokia actuator. So the filtering would have to be done in this actuator. Sadly I could not find a way to do it there. Maybe the MBean can be disabled directly in tomcat.
Please note: jolokia actuator is not available with spring boot 3!